# How can I run two docker machines in Jenkins to simulate ssh server and ssh client?

Tags: python, docker, jenkins, ssh, jenkins-pipeline

I'm testing a pipeline in which an ssh client talks to many servers to gather data from them. I currently test my software by spinning up a docker machine to simulate an ssh server. Now I want to automate testing in Jenkins. **How can I spin up docker ssh servers in Jenkins that don't act as agents but rather wait for an agent to contact them with an ssh request?** Here's the current Jenkins pipeline below. The dockerfile creates the machine that runs the python script but I need to create a docker ssh server for it to talk to.

```
pipeline {
    agent { dockerfile true }
    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
            steps {
                checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'somecredentials', url: 'a git repo']]])
            }
        }
        stage('Run Tests') {
            steps {
                sh "python ./rsyncUnitTests.py"
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        failure {
            sendEmail('foo@bar.org')
        }
        changed {
            sendEmail('foo@bar.org')
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To do this, one needs to use the scripting pipeline for Jenkins and the Docker Pipeline Plugin. You can create a docker machine outside of an agent.

Comment: You don't typically run SSH sessions in a container, but where exactly are you stuck doing so? Install openssh-server and run it

Comment: I've actually solved the problem. The tricky bit is getting then to talk to each other over a docker network. See https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/